# Inconsistent scope in python

Tags: python, function, scope

I have tried creating a function like this:

```
n = ["one", "two"]
result=""
def join_strings(words):
  for word in words:
    result+=word
  return result
print (join_strings(n))
```

This does not work and outputs:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
```

**The result variable has to be inside** the function for it to work.

However, when I have this simple function:

```
x=3
def price():
  return (x+3)
print (price())
```

This works and prints the price, even though x is **outside** of the function. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no inconsistency as the examples you gave are different from each other. It would still fail in the second function if you have tried to assign `x` to itself, like:

```
>>> x = 3
>>> def price():
...     x +=3
...     return x
...
>>> price()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

Instead of assigning back to `x` if you choose another name, it would run with no problem:

```
>>> def price():
...     y  = x + 3
...     return y
...
>>> price()
6
```

#### But, why it happens?

It's because Python's scoping rules. You can read the value of a variable outside of function but you can't *change* it**. When you do `x += 3`, which is same as `x = x + 3` for integers, that means "*I have a variable `x` that I have write access to it in the current scope.*" You don't have such variable, thus as the error says: you are referencing a "local variable" before assignment.

#### Is there a way to modify them in the function?

Yes. You can use `global` keyword, changes will be applied to your global variable:

```
>>> x = 3
>>> def price():
...     global x
...     x += 3
...     return x
...
>>> x
3
>>> price()
6
>>> x
6
```

** By *changing*, I mean assigning something else to it so it's `id` will change.

Comment: ... Or just add a parameter to the function so it can be passed the object to operate on and not rely on a variable in the outer scope.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in the second example you aren't trying to modify or reassign `x`.  (You'll get the same error if you say something like `x += 3` in the `price` function.)  Once you use an assignment operator, you're binding a new value to that name, shadowing the outer scope.

If you want to be able to modify something from an outer scope, put it inside a mutable container (like a list); you can then modify the contents without reassigning that variable.

```
result = [""]
def join_strings(words):
    for word in words:
        result[0] += word
    return result[0]
```

If you just want to be able to reference the `result` value, without modifying it, that's fine too, but you have to assign it to a new variable then:

```
result = ""
def join_strings(words):
    ret = result
    for word in words:
        ret += word
    return ret
```